# HTML dropdown appears empty in Android lollipop

Tags: android, html, cordova, select, android-5.0-lollipop

In phonegap application the `html select option(dropdown) value is blank`. That is shown white screen options instead of dropdown values but when click the option able to get the value from that.

This issue occur in only **Android Lollipop** devices( tested in nexus 4 and nexus 7 devices) other devices display correctly.

HTML code is:

```
<select id="selectlanguage" onchange="selectLangauge();">
    <option value="english">English</option>
    <option value="hindi">Hindi</option>
</select>
```

[image]

Comment: It will sound weird but I've a feeling. try changing the option color style.

Comment: it works perfectly fine on my android lollipop (moto g 2nd gen). by seeing the screenshot you have put up, are you using any UI design frameworks ??

Comment: @KRIZTE yes i am using jquery mobile...if i remove the JQM then also same(white screen only appeared)..

Comment: @AtanuCSE I tried with background color and color properties not affecting the option properties..text color is not available for options..

Answer (score 3):

This is a known problem with Android WebView on Lollipop.

https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=80909

One way to work around this is by generating a DIV that displays the list, essentially replacing the OPTIONs.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. My workaround is to use this jquery tool (select2) to replace all selects.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/3.5.2/select2.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/select2/3.5.2/select2.min.js"></script>

<select >
   <option value = "1" selected>Value 1</option>
   <option value="2">Value 2</option>
    <option value="3">Value 3</option>
</select>

<script>
// replace all select inputs with select2
$("select").select2();

// remove the search tool inside select2
$(".select2-search, .select2-focusser").remove(); 
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change in AndroidManifest:
`android:theme="@android:style/Theme.DeviceDefault.NoActionBar"` for `android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Light.NoTitleBar"`